# TypeError: users.map is not a function React js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

am stuck with a problem , am try to solve it lots of time but am not able to solve it , please try to fix my error. If you have any query please free feel to ask.

> Userdata.js

This is the userdata.js file where I want to load my all data which are in backend database

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Link,useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import Axios from 'axios';

const UserData = () => {
  const [users, setUser] = useState({
    title : "",
    description : ""
  });

  const {id} = useParams();

  useEffect(() => {
    AllUsers();
  }, []);

  const AllUsers = async () => {
    const res = await Axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/${id}`);
    console.log(res.data);
    setUser(res.data)
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="container">
        <table className="table table-hover table-bordered mt-5">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              {/* <th scope="col">No</th> */}
              <th scope="col">Title</th>
              <th scope="col">Details</th>
              <th scope="col">Action</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {users.map((user, index) => (
              <tr key={index}>
                <th scope="row">{user.id}</th>
                <td>{user.title}</td>
                <td>{user.description}</td>
              </tr>
            ))}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default UserData;
```

Comment: map function can be used for array type object. Here the 'users' state is of type object. Thats the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`users` looks to me to be an object, not an array. The `map()` function exists only on `Array`'s prototype, so you can't call it on your `users` object. Did you mean to initialize `users` like this?

```
 const [users, setUser] = useState([{
    title : "",
    description : ""
  }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `map` method is defined on on array and not on objects. Lets look at your code

```
  const [users, setUser] = useState({
    title : "",
    description : ""
  });
```

In `UserData` component you defined an object state with properties title and description. So `users` will be an object with those properties. Thus when you try to apply map on the `users` object it fails since map is not a function defined on objects.

Instead if you want to have an array of users with those two properties you can declare the state as follows

```
  const [users, setUser] = useState([{
    title : "",
    description : ""
  }]);
```